# hls is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

this is my configuration and I'm getting an error:

> 'hls' is not allowed here

```
  http {
access_log      logs/rtmp_access.log;
include         mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout   65;

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

location /hls {
            hls;
            hls_fragment            5s;
            hls_buffers             10 10m;
            hls_mp4_buffer_size     1m;
            hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
            root /run/shm;
        }
        #run/shm/hls/index.m3u8

    # rtmp stat
    location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
    }

    location /stat.xsl {
        # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
        root html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
}
```

so where do I suppose to put hls? I want to use http address and m3u8 file for show some video files on jwplayer

Comment: Do you use NGINX Plus, the paid version of NGINX? If not, you probably don't have the HLS module.

Comment: but it says that I put it in wrong place not "unknown directive"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NGINX Plus or the third party module, [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), for this functionality? Note that HLS support is not otherwise supported.

If you're using the third-party module reference the [nginx.conf example](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module#example-nginxconf) in the documentation.

(Disclaimer: I am affiliated with NGINX, Inc - the company that develops [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) and [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/)).